# Cannot figure out why window.frames.length = 0

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Before anyone asks why I'm using frames: At my job, I need to test a website that uses frames. I am experimenting with using Javascript to get some information from a frame, and I am having trouble getting frames to work, period.

First, just to experiment, I created a file on my machine, `test.html`. It loads two frames: the left one containing another test page I wrote (`test2.html`), and the right frame containing some web page.

```
<html>
<FRAMESET cols="20%, 80%">
    <FRAME name="leftFrame" src="test2.html">
    <FRAME name="rightFrame" src="http://www.foxnews.com/">
</FRAMESET>
</html>
```

This is my other test page, `test2.html`. It simply has a button which, when clicked, alerts you with the length of `window.frames`. From what I've found online, that should tell me the number of frames there are. Problem is, the result is zero.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doSomething() {
            alert(window.frames.length);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="doSomething();">
        Click me
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

How do you access a frame in JavaScript? I don't suppose this is issue comes from the fact that one of the frames points to a local file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `window` object doesn't refer to the entire browser window, but the logical window where the `document` object livs. The frameset, and each frame, has it's own `window` and `document` objects.

The window where the code is doesn't have any frames, you need to look at the parent window, where the frameset is:

```
alert(window.parent.frames.length);
```

Comment: I see. So, when I'm inside the frame, accessing `window` means that I am only accessing the "window" *of that frame*; but it isn't until I access `window.parent` (i.e., the parent window containing the frame) that I actually reach the "window" that represents the entire page. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have another question now. Indeed, `window.parent.frames.length` returns 2, as it should; and, if I pop up an alert for `typeof(window.parent.frames["rightFrame"])`, it returns "object" (which tells me that the frame has been found) ... but when I pop up an alert with `typeof(window.parent.frames["rightFrame"].document)`, nothing happens. It seems that I still can't access the "document", and therefore anything inside the frame. Thoughts?

Comment: Adding to that, here's some more, weird information. An alert for `typeof(window.parent.frames[0].document)` returns "object", as does `typeof(window.parent.frames[1])` ... but when I try to alert with `typeof(window.parent.frames[1].document)`, again, nothing happens. Very strange.

Comment: @DanielCharles: That frame contains a document from a different domain, so you are a victim of the same origin policy. You can see that the window is there, but you can't access anything in it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the link. So, because one page is from my local machine (with a URL of the form `file:///`), and another is from a webpage, they can't access each other. That's unfortunate for me, but makes sense.